# Python plt.hist() adding value.max() argument

Tags: python, matplotlib, max, histogram

I'm plotting a subset from a "Seattle Home Prices" dataset.
The attachment shows the results I get from two slightly different lines of code.

Their resulting graphs are almost the same, except that the 0-1 bin is broken out separately when the max() argument is present. Otherwise, it seems to get absorbed by the 0-2 bin.  Is this because the max() function is creates the correct number of bins, instead of defaulting to fewer?

plt.hist(small_data["BEDS"])

plt.hist(small_data["BEDS"],small_data["BEDS"].max())

[image]

Comment: You should call it as `plt.hist(small_data["BEDS"], bins=np.arange(-0.5, small_data["BEDS"].max()+1)` to make sure each of the integer data values fall nicely in the center of their own bin.  You could also use seaborn: `sns.histplot(x=small_data["BEDS"], discrete=True)` which will automatically set up the correct bins.

Answer (score 0):

When I was typing this out, it dawned on me that the answer is probably "Yes". Lmk if you disagree.

Comment: Yeah, the second argument is the number of bins and the max value would mean that you want that number of bins. If the bins were positive integers, then it would mean one bin for each number between 0 and the max. The only reason the first thing is kinda off is that the increments are 1.1, which means that things like 0 and 1 are in the same bin while everything else pretty much stays the same.